# Is it possible to define derivative for mapping from metric space to real line?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am trying to generalize the notion of $C^{\infty}(X)$ for $X$ is a metric space. Consider a continuous map $f$ from connected (complete) metric space $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, is it possible to define differentiation for $f$? Derivation seems a possible choice, any others?

**Edit**
The motivation is actually this: Given a commutative C* algebra, we can recover a compact Hausdorff space by Gelfand duality. Now if we choose this algebra be $C^{\infty}(X)$ for X is a Riemannian manifold, we can recover $X$ by Connes's reconstruction theorem(with other data such as Dirac operator and Hilbert space). Then I wonder what if $X$ is some arbitrary compact Hausdorff space? Then I realize that there are no notion of differentiation in such kind of space, even $X$ is metric space. If we define suitable notion of derivative for that space, can we recover any information from $X$?

(An example will be if we know how many different derivatives on function can have, can we know the dimension of X? Just like the partial derivatives case in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.)

Comment: There are many generalized derivatives. Please be more specific about what you are looking for or trying to accomplish.

Comment: What do you mean in this context by "derivation"?

Comment: @MichaelHardy I mean derivation defined on the $C(X)$. I know the set of derivation $Der(C(X))$ is zero if the derivation acting on the whole set, but maybe it can act as an unbounded linear operator with restricting domain

Comment: From the geometric analysis perspective, the standard replacement of differentiable functions are (locally) Lipschitz functions. (See for instance Heinonen's book "Lectures on Lipschitz Analysis.) It would help if you edit your question and explain better what are you interested in and why.

Comment: I think, in your edit you mean "$X$ is a smooth manifold." (You cannot recover the Riemannian metric from the algebra of smooth functions!) The question is a bit better now, but is still unclear to me what exactly you want to recover in $X$: Is it the metric? You can recover its Lipschitz-equivalence class from the algebra of Lipschitz functions. (See my answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/319737/what-is-the-structure-preserved-by-strong-equivalence-of-metrics/320389#320389).)

Comment: As for the metric up to isometry, I do not know, sounds very unlikely that there is a similar theorem along these lines.

Comment: Here's one way: you can always use Kuratowski embedding to treat $X$ as a subset of some Banach space (if $X$ is compact or bounded only then the embedding is canonical). Then your differentiation can be defined as Frechet derivative.